# flickr widget in orchardcms

Tags: orchardcms

I downloaded and installed flickr widget in orchard cms but i am gettin exception like

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'gLoad'

please do this helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You should try to contact the author for that module. There is a contact link on the gallery page.

Comment: Or take a look at the code and try to fix it and submit the fix.